# delete files with particular character length and a extension in a directory using some command in terminal window

Tags: command-line, bash, files, delete

I would like to know what command must be executed in the terminal window which will enable us to delete files with a particular extension(say .c) in a particular directory whose name length is 6 characters. If not possible even a bash script consisting of a series of commands is also acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove all files in the current directory that ends with '.c' and is exactly 6 characters long?

```
rm ????.c
```

EDIT: or with absolute path:

```
rm /Folder1/Folder2/.../FolderN/??????.c
```

where folders are path To Your dir. For example:

```
rm /home/MyUserDir/Files/??????.c
```